# Loop JSON using JavaScript and create dynamic HTML table

Tags: javascript, json, html, rest

I'm trying to loop through a JSON object from a REST endpoint. I've successfully iterated through the JSON array and created a dynamic table based on the variables I created from the JSON object.

The issues I'm having is creating a separate table for each location. For example, I would like each location to be their own row, and the associated camera position with its photo as separate cells. Instead, my table is coming out as one column, one row.

Here is what my code looks like (please disregard my amateur coding abilities, as I'm still learning) :) :

```js
function getJSON(url) {

            var resp = '';
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            if (xmlHttp != null) {
                xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
                xmlHttp.send(null);
                resp = xmlHttp.responseText;
            }

            return resp;

        }

        function getAllLocations() {

            gjson = getJSON(
                'https://gis.iowadot.gov/public/rest/services/Maintenance/RWIS_Data/FeatureServer/5/query?where=1%3D1&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&distance=&units=esriSRUnit_Foot&relationParam=&outFields=CAMERA_POSITION%2C+SITE_NUMBER%2C+RPUID_NAME%2C+IMAGE_URL&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnExtentOnly=false&orderByFields=RPUID_NAME+ASC%2C+CAMERA_POSITION+ASC&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&multipatchOption=&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&f=pjson'
            );

            var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(gjson);
            var features = parsedJSON.features;

            return features;

        }

        /*
        creates the table. 
        */
        function getJSON(url) {

            var resp = '';
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            if (xmlHttp != null) {
                xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
                xmlHttp.send(null);
                resp = xmlHttp.responseText;
            }

            return resp;

        }

        function getAllLocations() {

            gjson = getJSON(
                'https://gis.iowadot.gov/public/rest/services/Maintenance/RWIS_Data/FeatureServer/5/query?where=1%3D1&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&distance=&units=esriSRUnit_Foot&relationParam=&outFields=CAMERA_POSITION%2C+SITE_NUMBER%2C+RPUID_NAME%2C+IMAGE_URL&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnExtentOnly=false&orderByFields=RPUID_NAME+ASC%2C+CAMERA_POSITION+ASC&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&multipatchOption=&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&f=pjson'
            );

            var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(gjson);
            var features = parsedJSON.features;

            return features;

        }

        /*
        creates the table. 
        */
        function createLocationTable() {

            var features = getAllLocations();
            var site_number = '';
            var sitename = '';
            var cameraPostion = '';
            var imgURL = '';
            var date = new Date();
            var content = '';

            content = '<table align="center">';
            content += '<tr><th class="table-header">';
            content += '<center>RWIS Images</center></th></tr></table>'
            content += '<table><tbody>';
            var tempSiteName = features[0].attributes.SITE_NUMBER;
            content += '<tr>';
            for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {

                site_number = features[i].attributes.SITE_NUMBER
                sitename = features[i].attributes.RPUID_NAME;
                cameraPostion = features[i].attributes.CAMERA_POSITION;
                imgURL = features[i].attributes.IMAGE_URL;

                //if(tempSiteName.toString().substr(0,tempSiteName.toString().indexOf(' ')) != sitename.toString().substr(0,sitename.toString().indexOf(' ')))
                if (tempSiteName != sitename) {
                    //then create a new row
                    tempSiteName = sitename;
                    content += '</tr>';
                    content += '<tr>';
                }
                //otherwise everythind goes side to side
                content += '<td><center><b><br>' + sitename + '</b> -</br></center><center>' + cameraPostion +'</center>';
                content += '<div><a href =' + imgURL + ' target="_blank"><center><img src=' + imgURL +
                    ' class="imgRWIS" height="100" width="150"></center></div></td>';

            }
            content += '</tbody></table>';
            document.write(content)

            return content;
        }

        window.onload = createLocationTable();
```

```css
body {
            font-family: Arial, 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
        }

        .table-header {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #d46200;
        }
        .sitename h{
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #7c9f3d;
        }

        .table-location {
            /*  background: #dddddd; */
            width: auto;
            margin: 10px 0;
            font-size: 14px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .table-location td {
            padding: 5px;
        }

        img.imgRWIS {
            background: black;
            position: relative;
            padding: 1px;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
```

Comment: EDIT: I updated the code snippet to reflect the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand this is what you want

```js
function getJSON(url) {

var resp = '';
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

if (xmlHttp != null) {
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    resp = xmlHttp.responseText;
}

return resp;

}

function getAllLocations() {

gjson = getJSON(
    'https://gis.iowadot.gov/public/rest/services/Maintenance/RWIS_Data/FeatureServer/5/query?where=1%3D1&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&distance=&units=esriSRUnit_Foot&relationParam=&outFields=CAMERA_POSITION%2C+SITE_NUMBER%2C+RPUID_NAME%2C+IMAGE_URL&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnExtentOnly=false&orderByFields=RPUID_NAME+ASC%2C+CAMERA_POSITION+ASC&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&multipatchOption=&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&f=pjson'
);

var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(gjson);
var features = parsedJSON.features;

return features;

}

    /*
    creates the table. 
    */
function createLocationTable() {

var features = getAllLocations();
var site_number = '';
var sitename = '';
var cameraPostion = '';
var imgURL = '';
var date = new Date();
var content = '';

content = '<table class="table-location"><tbody>';
content += '<tr><th class="table-header">';
content += '<center>Images</center></th></tr>';
var tempSiteNumber = features[0].attributes.SITE_NUMBER;
content += '<tr>';
content += '<tr><th class="table-header">';
content += '<center>' + features[0].attributes.RPUID_NAME + '</center></th></tr>';
for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {

    site_number = features[i].attributes.SITE_NUMBER
    sitename = features[i].attributes.RPUID_NAME;
    cameraPostion = features[i].attributes.CAMERA_POSITION;
    imgURL = features[i].attributes.IMAGE_URL;               
    
    if (tempSiteNumber != site_number)
    {
        //then create a new row
                                     
        tempSiteNumber = site_number;
        content += '</tr>';                
        content += '<tr>';
        content += '<tr><th class="table-header">';
        content += '<center>'+sitename+'</center></th></tr>';
    }
    //otherwise everythind goes side to side
    content += '<td>' + cameraPostion;
    content += '<div><a href =' + imgURL + ' target="_blank"><center><img src=' + imgURL +' class="imgRWIS" height="125" width="250"></center></div></td>';
  
}
content += '</tbody></table>';
document.write(content)

return content;
}

window.onload = createLocationTable();
```

```css
body {
            font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        .table-header {
            background: #D07D0E;
        }

        .table-location {
            /*  background: #dddddd; */
            width: auto;
            margin: 10px 0;
            font-size: 14px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .table-location td {
            padding: 5px;
        }

        img.imgRWIS {
            background: black;
            position: relative;
            padding: 1px;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

All you had to do is manage different "names", skip a line when it's different, otherwise all goes on the same line

***EDIT***

In order to have title over images you have to use a display block container like a Div.

There you go, all problems fixed.

Comment: Feel free to ask if there's something you don't understand in the snippet of code.

Comment: Now how would I get the sitename to be the headers over each image?

Comment: I'll have a look, here's the new condition to fix problem for Cedar Rapids..
if(tempSiteName.toString().substr(0,tempSiteName.toString().indexOf(' ')) != sitename.toString().substr(0,sitename.toString().indexOf(' ')))
I also updated the snippet of code.

Comment: That fixed the Cedar Rapids issue, but it now input several sitenames on one row, instead of a sitename having its own row.

Comment: i fixed last problem !

Comment: Yep, that was it! @TinkeringMatt

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your `<tr>` tag.

```
content += '<tr><td><b>' + sitename + '</b> - ' + cameraPostion + '</td>';
content += '<td><a href =' + imgURL + ' target="_blank"><center><img src=' + imgURL +' class="imgRWIS" height="125" width="200"></center></td></tr>';
```

The content inside `<tr>` and `</tr>` makes for one row.
The content inside `<td>` and `</td>` makes for one column.

Comment: Could also add colspan to the <th> to extend the header over both columns if desired.

content += '<tr><th class="table-header" colspan=2>';

Comment: I want to show each camera position with sitename in one row and the corresponding image underneath it in a separate row. I would like the images for each site to be in their own row per site. So you'd have a row of images from one single site, then a row below that from one single site, and so forth.